# How is the current for the Dirac equation derived?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, dirac-equation, noethers-theorem

Why is it that the derivative of the current $j^\mu$ is the difference between the Dirac equation and its adjoint?

Comment: Can you explain this question more. What is $j$? Write some equations.

Comment: Assuming that $j^\mu$ is a Noether current, what symmetry are you referring to? Space-time translations, Lorentz symmetry, internal vector symmetry, or the axial symmetry? I have downvoted your question, because I think it is unclear.

Comment: @Hunter: As I stated in my answer, I'm pretty sure he's referring to internal vector symmetry as to prove it is conserved one must, as the OP stated, use the Dirac equation for $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$.

Comment: @JamalS fair enough. I guess you're right, but I still think the OP has not really put in a lot of effort to formulate his question.

Comment: @Hunter: I agree 100% with you, but it might as well be answered, It's been forgotten since 2013.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Dirac Lagrangian has what is commonly called an 'internal vector symmetry'; if we perform a transformation on the Dirac spinor field given by,

$$\psi \to e^{-i\alpha}\psi$$

the corresponding conserved current by Noether's theorem is given by, $j^\mu=\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi$. We can explicitly verify it is conserved:

$$\partial_\mu j^\mu = (\partial_\mu\bar{\psi})\gamma^\mu \psi + \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu (\partial_\mu \psi) =im\bar{\psi}\psi -im\bar{\psi}\psi=0$$

where, as the OP noted, we have used the equations of motion:

$$i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi = m\psi \quad \quad i \partial_\mu \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu =-m\bar{\psi}$$

which arise by varying the Lagrangian with respect to $\psi$ and $\bar{\psi}$ respectively. The conserved charge due to the conserved current is given by,

$$Q=\int \mathrm{d}^3 x \, \psi^{\dagger}\psi $$

which may be interpreted as electric charge, or after quantization, fermion number.